# My swap isn't working. I think I messed it up

Tags: usb, mount, swap

Recently my swap was still working, but today I found it isn't anymore. I *think it has something to do with the fact that last week a USB-stick wasn't mounting, so I tried mounting it manually, but accidentally tought the swap partition was the USB drive. I'm not sure what I did anymore though.

I just tried enabling it by running `sudo swapon -a`. That ends without error, but the swap still displays as "Not available" in the system monitor.

Does anybody know how I can enable the swap again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the gnome disk utility on the left choose /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 and on the right bellow should be a play sign click to mount partition.